# Problems with CORS using localhost on agora io sdk 4

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am trying to use agora io sdk 4 and the server responds with CORS problems.

[Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xd7R.png)

```js
import AgoraRTC from "agora-rtc-sdk-ng"

async function joinAgora(){
  const client = AgoraRTC.createClient({
      mode: 'rtc',
      codec: 'vp8'
  });


  try{
      const uid = await client.join(constants.AGORA_API_KEY,"SOME_ROOM", null, "GENERATE_UID")
      console.log("join success", uid);
  }catch (e){
      console.log("join failed", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code fragment is not executable from the web, I just wanted to write a reference of what I have in my code, according to the agora documentation it only allows access from http: // localhost (http://127.0.0.1) and it does not work for me with either host (https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_web_ng?platform=Web)

Comment: here is what it prints me in console by localhost https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xd7R.png

Comment: The server will need to be configured to output the necessary CORS header(s). Your code looks like JavaScript, although you do not say if it is Nodejs. See https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/faq/call_api_in_browser?platform=RESTful

Comment: I solved this issue, I did removed the node_module folder and success, thank you everyone for all support